# Does Thinfinity Virtual UI work with embedded browsers (Cefsharp)?

Tags: winforms, cefsharp, embedded-browser, winforms-to-web

[image]My company wants to try out the library "Thinfinity Virtual UI", to run a Windows Forms application in a browser.
It seems to more or less work, though the application crashes everytime an embedded browser is attached to the form (Cefsharp), see attached image.

I am not able to catch the error in the try/catch.

Any ideas how to remedy/debug this issue?

I tried searching the web for a solution/alternative to CefSharp, looking at error logs, inserting the try/catch. I also wrote to the company, but so far I get no reply.

Comment: Crashing check the log file for errors see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#log-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Luke and I work at Cybele Software where we developed Thinfinity VirtualUI to help Windows developers converting their Legacy Windows Applications into modern Web Applications by just modifying one single line of code and adding our libraries.

Unfortunately, as it is, WebView and Chromium are not supported in our propietary protocol. But do not worry, we have 2 valid workarounds.

1. **Using our HTMLDOC demo**. Link to our GitHub [HERE](https://github.com/cybelesoft/virtualui/tree/master/C%23)

This demo shows how to programatically create an iframe inside your application (using HTMLDOC.CreateComponent) , and how to communicate back and forward between the application and the website running inside that iframe, using Javascript Remote Objects (JSRO)

2. **Using our 'Third Party Applications' Feature**. Link on how to enable this [HERE](https://www.cybelesoft.com/blog/integrate-and-publish-any-third-party-application-using-thinfinity-virtualui-3-0/)

Be aware that to enable this feature, you'll need to have our Thinfinity Broker and your app running on a Windows Server. Basically, with this option, you'll be using a Microsoft feature called 'Desktop Duplication' where we can eventually render any Third Party application with the help of Remote Desktop Services.

I hope this does the trick for you and don't hesitate on contacting us about this or any other doubt you may have about our products :)

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply!

We are also having problems with opening links in the users default internet browser - Do you also have a work around for this?

Comment: You can use our OpenLinkDlg Method to open the end-users browser with a URL. You can follow one of our tutorials with multiple use-cases for this method (you trigger a mailto: reference on the end user as well) and you can find it in the following URL https://www.cybelesoft.com/blog/send-an-email-from-outlook-or-open-a-second-application-using-openlinkdlg/

I'm also sharing with you a link to our documentation on this with other methods to implement as well :) https://files.cybelesoft.com/manuals/symbolreference/00393.html